# How to change the position of thumbnail images randomly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have 12 images in a thumbnail view and I want to change their position randomly on the click of a refresh button, so that my images are the same but their position changes in the thumbnail view. Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

use int r = arc4random()%12;

and change position  of your buttons according to r.

for your width and height remain as it is , and change x and y position according to random number.

HI , I am using Unbutton instead of UIImage view because i have not different images.and for UI connivence, U have to replace Unbutton with imageViews ..enjoy it.

**.h file :** UIButton         *b[12];
**.m file :**

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

 float y = 10;
 int x = 0;
 int count = 0;
 for (int i = 0 ; i < 12; i++)
{
    count ++;
    b[i] = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    b[i].frame =  CGRectMake(x, y, 100, 100);
    [b[i] setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i+1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    x = x + 105;
    [self.view addSubview:b[i]];
    if(count == 3)
    {
        count = 0;
        x = 0;
        y = y+ 105;
    }


}
```

}

```
    - (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
   {
int n = 12;
int temp;
for (int i = 0 ; i < 12 ; i++)
{
     int r = arc4random()%n;
    if(r != temp){
    temp = r;
        CGRect r1 = b[i].frame;      
    b[i].frame = b[temp].frame;
        b[temp].frame = r1; 

    n--;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: if possible than please give me demo for 3 images.

Comment: Thanks man(PJR)..i don't know your name but it's useful tutorial for me...Nice Work Man

Comment: hi you like it then accept my answer by check yes symobol and make it gerren hence other can use it and by checking answer you can gain 2 point in stack overflow. and also increase your acceptance percentage.